# Converting map to list return TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert map to list, but it's returned `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.. can someone explain to me?

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(n, input().split()))
for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

Error:

```
arr = list(map(n, input().split()))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map function in Python accepts the first argument as a callable function and the second as an iterable. Each item in the iterable is then passed through the function into an output `map` object.

In your example, `n` is defined as an `int` pulled from the Stdin (input) due to the line `n = int(input())`. Therefore, the code above is equivalent to the following:

```
n = int(input())
out = []

for element in input().split():
    out.append( n(element) )
```

This code won't run because `n` (as an `int`) cannot be called as a function.

If what you are trying to do is convert input like `0 2 45 119` to a list of integers, you can pass the first argument of `map` as `int`, and `int` will be called on every element of the input provided.

Comment: oh.. i see. but, how to add the range of the map? i use "n" as the first argument to give the range of map

Comment: @EzraLazuardy what makes you think you need to provide a range to the map function? Doku: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map